# Identifying monopole antenna with ground connected coil

Tags: identification, antenna, design, coil, waveguide

I can’t find any information on what this design of antenna is called, it has a monopole wire connected to the signal pin of an SMA connector, the coil is connected to ground. The larger diameter antenna pictured is a quad band GSM antenna from Adafruit, not sure of the manufacturer. The smaller diameter is a 915 MHz antenna from Amazon sold by a company DIYmalls. For the larger antenna, the monopole is 1/10 lambda and the spacing between coil wraps is 1/100 lambda for 915 MHz. I was able to replicate the design successfully by measuring the dimensions, but to use the design in a capstone project I need to show the derivation of the parameters/dimensions.

What is a name of this form of antenna? Is there a way I can model this antenna?

Edit: I purchased the antenna, I don’t need to identify the manufacturer or the specs. I am interested in identifying the method used to synthesize this design. Following the derivation for a helical antenna gives different dimensions, which makes sense b cause the coil/helix is grounded and the monopole is connected to signal.

[image: antenna in question (top design is referenced in post)]

Comment: It can be any antenna, without any identifying marks, no one can tell.

Comment: "*we’re only allowed to order from Amazon*" <-- that is contrary to all things that are sensible to electrical/electronic engineers and even more so for someone undertaking a capstone project. Amazon do not publish data sheets along with their questionable electronic component offerings and, data sheets are fundamental to quality assessment of any supplier plus, a DS is a de facto standard for what the components purchased actually do (in detail).

Comment: The Amazon thing is especially frustrating, almost every group in my class is struggling without digikey or mouser to buy from. The site I bought it from, adafruit, states specs that I verified but doesn’t provide datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this operates as follows: for bands around 2GHz it acts like a simple monopole (the center wire), and for bands around 900MHz it acts like a normal mode helix (the outer spiral).  Both these modes are quite efficient and this could be a good antenna.

It is wrong to simply dismiss all compact antennas as inefficient.  If it is an antenna like https://www.adafruit.com/product/1859 then I have no reason to doubt the claimed gain of 2dBi over quite a wide range of frequencies.  Not fantastic, but a perfectly reasonable antenna.

[image]

You might want to read up on helical antennas:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helical_antenna

Here is a paper that analyses something similar, it may give you some ideas:

Yan Wai Chow, E. K. N. Yung and Hon Tat Hui, "Dual frequency monopole-helical antenna by using a parasitic normal mode helix for mobile handsets," 2000 Asia-Pacific Microwave Conference.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/925987

[image: Image from paper]
<sup>"Antenna Configuration" from the paper cited</sup>

Just to answer a few of the questions raised in the comments:

To an antenna designer, this antenna

[image]

can readily be decomposed into a monopole and a helix.  Given the frequency bands of operation it is easy to see that the monopole could be responsible for the high band and the helix, operating in normal mode, could be responsible for the low band.  Given the lack of a direct connection, the helix is being excited parasitically.

The paper cited shows something **similar**, and was quoted to hopefully help the OP with some analysis.  I never said it was the **same** antenna, I quoted it to show that the parasitic excitation of the helix is feasible.  For the antenna in the paper, the idea that  that the only part of the monopole that radiates is the little bit protruding from the end of the helix is, from my experience in antennas, unlikely.

I suspect that in the paper that they may have analyzed it over a groundplane, this was a common design starting point (particularly in 2000), for antennas put on small boxes.  They clearly thought that the antenna didn't need an infinite groundplane as the title of the paper is "..for mobile handsets".  The infinite groundplane is not essential, as it isn't for every other monopole antenna.  Nor is it necessary for parasitic excitation of the helix.  Both antennas almost certainly work better when attached to a small box or PCB.

Other comments on this thread cast doubt on the utility of VSWR in designing antennas.  Antenna designers find return loss (or VSWR) a very useful parameter as at those frequencies where power isn't reflected to the source it is generally radiated.  Of course you have to understand the losses in your antenna (and check that someone hasn't soldered a 50 ohm load at the feedpoint).

Comment: This is the exact antenna it is, I bought it on adafruit.

Comment: So at 900MHz it is probably acting as a normal mode helix, the only unusual thing is the way of coupling to the helical coil, with it grounded at the base and excited by the inner conductor.  I don't have details on how to determine the coupling, and it may have been designed empirically.  From electromagnetics it is perfectly reasonable though that the coupling is sufficient to efficiently radiate at 900MHz, and the specs would support this.

Comment: This paper looks very close to the design, thank you for the help. This should give me enough to start with.

Comment: If we discuss an antenna that uses a different mode of operation at ~900 MHz than at ~2000MHz, and works well at both of these frequencies, it need not work well at 1500MHz, so I suggest to avoid talking about "a wide range of frequencies", as it actually seems like two "narrow" bands, but it weill be a bad antenna between those two bands. Given that mobile phones are basically confined to those bands, being a bad antenna at 1500MHz is not an issue for using it as mobile phone antenna - but it will likely not be useful as GSM antenna.

Comment: Added the figure from the paper to the question; I am nto fully convinced we're doing the same here; even if we fully ignore the "top" coil, this antenna differs in two IMHO *key* points: 1. no ground plane , 2. \$L < H_2\$. Are you sure this is the same design,  @Tesla23 ? The idea of the paper is that the monopole conductor (a helically loaded one) is supported by the outer coil, i.e. what they call "parasitic". For that to make sense, the existence of a ground plane is quite important. And the idea seems to be that there's a part of the monopole protuding from the outer coil, to emit.

Comment: From making a few antennas and experimenting with them, the coil being the same length or shorter than the monopole kills the response all together. Widening the spacing on the coil wraps gives better attenuation and will slightly change the center frequency, and a longer/shorter monopole shifts the frequency as expected. I haven’t tried much with the diameter of the coil yet.

Comment: I'd expect the two modes to interact considerably, in particular I'd suspect that the monopole would have a major effect on the helix. Good luck with your experiments.

Answer (score 1):

First off: note that "cheap and compact 915 MHz" antenna nowhere claims "good antenna". This might simply be a compromise between "easy and cheap to manufacture" and "everything unless designed not to is an antenna, it's just that some are better and we call 'em that".  It being the best you've tested can mean many things!

I've not seen that antenna design before – so you might be in the position to invent a name.

I **suspect** the radiative mechanism is dominated by the following:

Functionally, for windings much smaller than the wavelength, the coil together with the center monopole still forms a coax waveguide - but only of sorts:

The coax mainly carries an (approximate) TEM mode, such that currents in the shield run longitudinal to the cable length, and the E-field points radially between shield and center conductor.

Now, that wave hits the coil section: suddenly the currents *can't* run longitudinally anymore; there's simply no connection in that direction; you're forcing moding on the wave. Usually, the first higher-order mode that appears on coax is TE11, but I don't think that is a solution under these boundary conditions; long story short, the E-field gets a longitudinal component, the H-field both a transversal and a radial component, because there's no option to just continue propagating as done within the coax. Because currents in the shield cannot compensate that, the such-formed waveguide becomes leaky, and thus, an antenna.

Good luck analytically modelling that! This is something that you can, given non-zero wire diameters, probably can, at best, simulate somewhat reliably. So, simulate. I'd call that "pretty advanced", should you go for it.

Comment: I’m not sure what the first part of your post is about, the antenna is both the best out of the 8 we characterized and an objectively good antenna with a swr of 1.1869 using an Agilent E5071C. I also would assume two different antennas I purchased, one cheap from Amazon and one not very cheap from adafruit, with the same ground coil design and center monopole is a novel design so I don’t think I’ll name it. I’ve successfully recreated the antenna physically and tested it by tuning, I was hoping to find the name of the design to derive the dimensions before designing in HFSS for simulation.

Comment: The first part was just a warning that this antenna was probably a result of *trying really long and really hard* to make a cheap antenna! So, there's not going to be a lot of "textbook" in it, and a lot of "antenna engineer hand-tuning simulations together with a mechanical engineer fine-tuning manufacturing". (also, while I don't believe this to be the case here: be careful when people try to sell you antennas with great VSWR; a proper terminating resistor also has perfect VSWR. I always found it surprising people are comparing their antennas that way. But people do as people do…)

Comment: And the rest of my answer addresses why I don't think there's a name for this antenna.

Comment: I think I assumed that it was a proven design there would be information on and I just didn’t know the name to google to find it. After looking through my textbooks and a lot of googling and asking antenna design engineers I’ve come up with nothing, maybe it is some random design. The vswr is as advertised, 1.23 measured compared to <=2 advertised and gives good S11 on the network analyzer.

Comment: It seems very much to be a proven design, seeing you have two different antennas having it! It's just that it doesn't seem to a have a "textbook name", if you will. I don't think the design is *random* (*random antennas* are a thing, and this is not a *random antenna*), I think it was thought up by someone, then hand-optimized, then further optimized, then commercialized.

Comment: And again, good VSWR is necessary, not sufficient, for a good antenna. VSWR and S11 tell you about the same thing (how much energy the antenna reflects back into the cable) and nothing about the relevant thing (how much energy actually gets radiated in a useful way, and how much gets converted to heat or radiates in undesired directions).